# Unable To Bind Current data context in UWP

Tags: mvvm, uwp, uwp-xaml

How to get current page element name if data context set from the view model
Please check image for  Code and description, [Code Descriptioon](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Tyi1xXureo8L8kxE75jjk0PlYPqvDGPR/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hello, can you provide us with more details on what you are using as a framework model for MVVM, and if your binding does not work completely or only in some cases.

Comment: Could you paste the code and image here? We can't access the link.

Comment: If you have a view model, you have a collection or a property which is bound the said element name. You need not modify the element by name in the view model.

Comment: Please try to give the viewmodel instance a X:Name and access with x:bind `MyViewModel.SaveButton`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your requirement,  Please try to give the **viewmodel** instance a `x:Name` and access with x:Bind `MyViewModel.SaveButton`